# Ember data side loading with JSONAPI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

The request generated for my route is `http://api.myApp.com/tags/123/products`, but I need to do some side loading to improve performance, the desired XHR would be:

`http://api.myApp.com/tags/123/products?include=sideload1,sideload2,sideload3`

My router looks like this:

```
  this.route('tags', function() {
    this.route('tag', { path: ':id' }, function() {
      this.route('products', function() {

      });
    });
  });
```

I'll like to sideload some async models for products, currently I have:

```
// app/routes/tags/tag/products.js

model() {
    return this.modelFor('tags.tag').get('products');
}
```

How would I go about adding query params in route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar in a project and `store.query(type, { query });` has worked for me. http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_query-and-queryrecord

Try doing a `store.query` when defining your model and passing in

```
{include: "sideload1,sideload2,sideload3"}
```

Another option could be creating an adapter for your model and using `buildURL` to add on the query params... However this is a bit hacky and shouldn't be necessary if your API is following the JSON API standards.

```
App.TagsAdapter = DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    buildURL: function(type, id) {
        var baseURL = 'http://api.myApp.com/tags/123/products';
        var method = '?include=sideload1,sideload2,sideload3';

        return baseURL + method;
    }
});
```